# ping hostnames using avahi @ Ubuntu in VMware. No resolving

Tags: vmware, ping, hostname, mdns, avahi

I'm having a really strange problem. I have 2 virtual machines running ubuntu 11.4 in VMware player. These virtual machines have a bridged connection to my network. Since they use DHCP it would be more easy to let them talk to each other using hostnames instead of IP addresses.

That is where the it becomes a strange situation.

```
ping 192.168.0.10 //this is machine 1 
ping 192.168.0.11 //this is machine 2
```

both work like a charm

```
ping machine1.local  
ping machine2.local
```

work great on their own system. but ping machine1.local on machine 2 results in a "ping: unknown host machine1.local"

After trying and checking everything and getting nothing but the local machine in the avahi-browse, I installed wireshark to get to know what's really going on.

I ran wireshark, and then ran avahi-browse. In wireshark I saw all the responses to the MDNS message AND I GOT machine1.local AND machine2.local!!!

GREAT! but when I turned off wireshark the avahi-browse cache went empty again...

Why is it that when I have wireshark on in the virtual machine, the avahi-daemon gets the MDNS messages, and when I turn it off, the messages get lost again...

Comment: Did I find a new bug no-one ever found before? Or is my question not clear enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to switch to the e1000 network adapter to (fully) support multicast. To switch to the e1000, open your vmx file in an editor and find the entry for the virtual ethernet adapters. Change or add this line:

**ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"**

(If you have more than one adapter, change it for each of ethernet0, ethernet1, etc.)

This thread details some of the multicast issues that seem similar to yours:

- http://communities.vmware.com/message/1549658

This document describes the various possible virtual adapters and their limitations and capabilities:

- http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1001805